# Use Private FRamework in Xcode Celestial

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, private, silent

I'm a Xcode beginner so I would really appreciates if the answers were as much detailed as possible (if image could be included it would be best)

I would like to use the celestial private framework, I do not care if it get rejected by the app store since it's a private project.
I would like to use the AVSystemController in the celestial framework.
If I go to the xcode directory, I find only an exec file in the framework.
I found the headers files at:
https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-

download:

https://github.com/masbog/PrivateFrameworkHeader-iOS-iPhone-5.-/archive/master.zip

The questions are:

1-Do I add the framework that's included in the xcode directory the one that has only on file (exec named Celestial)? or should I add a headers folder first and put all the downloaded headers in it?

2-IS Github a trusted site? btw I couldn't help but noticing that the downloaded zip file headers (at least the AVSystemContriller.h ) are different then the ones you directly open on the website

3-After adding the the celestial framework (in the linked Binary with librairy of the project ) to use it I should use #import  but I get an error not found

The purpose of this project is to turn the iphone to silent profile by code.
Please Help, I've been reading threads all over the internet and I wasn't able to solve it.

P.S.: Like I said before I am a beginner so it would be appreciated to detail you answer as much as possible

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

dumping private header is for helping you to find functional without documentation, to load private framework you just type on your code like this :

```
NSBundle *b = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:@"/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/WhatEver.framework"];
```

that mean, you will load/use private framework at your iDevice :)